# Can't find address in abi encoded data of event

Tags: events, ganache, abi

I have an event with the signature Event(address, uint256, string) which my smart contract emit from time to time. I am testing said contract on a ganache test net where when the Ganache picks up these events, it decodes them perfectly. Yet when I try to decode the abi encoding of said event using the rpc-json response there seems to be something wrong with the encoding even though everything else (tx-hash etc.) lines up:

I tested with address being 0xa96403a52c4b63fefda2f24734a7c1f69a36b24a, the uint256 being 1 and the string being hello and get this result:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000568656c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is the uint256 which is 1:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

I don't know what this is:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is the length of the string, followed by the utf8 encoding of "hello", correctly by 27 bytes of padding to make it 32 bytes in total:

```
568656c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Could anyone help me out in decoding the address here and correct me in case I did something wrong decoding the other stuff? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Let me guess - the `address` parameter in your event is `indexed`? If yes, then it's not going to be provided in the `data` field, but in the `topics` array at the 2nd entry (i.e., `topics[1]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the details that you've posted, I believe that the `address` parameter in your event is `indexed`. Therefore, it is not going to be provided in the `data` string, but in the `topics` array at the 2nd entry (i.e., `topics[1]`).

If you want the actual address, then you can do:

```
const address = "0x" + topics[1].slice(26); // get rid of 24 leading zeros
```

Since the address has been fetched from an event, it's going to be all lower-case.

So if you're planning to compare it with other addresses, then you'd be better off with:

```
const address = Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x" + topics[1].slice(26));
```

As for the data-part which you were puzzled with (`0x00...40`), it is related to how dynamic-types (`string` in your case) are encoded; you can find a full explanation of that in [the documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types).

Comment: Thank you for your answer that's correct! Just out of curiosity, what is that abi encoded string in my data then?

Comment: @NicolasSchapeler: Please see updated answer.